# How to get recordtypeid from generic object

Tags: apex, controller, record-type, object, generics

I want to be able to pass an object, and recordtypelabel as string into a controller and get the recordtypeId. How do I achieve this. I currently get variable does not exist for the custom object.

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static Id getRecTypeId(String recordTypeLabel, string objectStr){
        SObjectType customObject = ((SObject) Type.forName(objectStr).newInstance()).getSObjectType();
        Id recid = Schema.SObjectType.customObject.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(recordTypeLabel).getRecordTypeId();        
        return recid;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Schema.SObjectType` has static members of only objects that are present in your organization. So you cannot access those members dynamically i.e. it will allow

```
Schema.sObjectType.Account
```

As per your code,

```
SObjectType customObject = ((SObject) Type.forName(objectStr).newInstance()).getSObjectType();
Schema.SObjectType.customObject
```

you are trying to access members of `SObjectType` class, using the instance of `sObjectType` which is incorrect.

Instead you can use [Schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm) class's `globalDescribe` method which will return `Map<String, Schema.SObjectType>`, from this map you can get the `sObjectType` of any object you need using the `name` of the object. Once you get the `sObjectType` for the object, then you can use `getDescribe()` method of [sObjectType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm#apex_class_Schema_SObjectType) class to get `Schema.DescribeSObjectResult` and then using its `getRecordTypeInfosByName()` method you can get record type information in [RecordTypeInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm) class.

Here is the code to access record type information using the object's name

```
SObjectType objToken = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectStr);
DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objToken.getDescribe();
Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapByName = objDef.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
Schema.RecordTypeInfo rtByName =  rtMapByName.get(recordTypeLabel);
Id recid = rtByName.getRecordTypeId();
```

Or in single line you could do

```
Id recid = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectStr).getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(recordTypeLabel).getRecordTypeId();
```